# default table prefix in persistence

Tags: java, spring, persistence

How to configure default table prefix in persistence configuration file. I'm using Spring's default configuration as follows:

```
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
  <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
     <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/spring-quickstart/persistence" />
     <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
  </properties>
```

thanks

Comment: Is [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#repositoryTablePrefix) maybe what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313095/jpa-hibernate-and-custom-table-prefixes) SO question has the answer you seek.

Looks like what G. Bach refers to only allows you to change "metadata tables"?