# HIBERNATE: Auto append word into TABLE

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

hi I have an entity with this annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REPORT_WORK")
```

But for some reason hibernate keep saying Missing Table: `REPORT_REPORT_WORK`

I know that is the problem because of when I change the name to `"REPORT_WORKX"`

It will say Missing Table: `REPORT_REPORT_WORKX`

Has any encountered this issue before?

Update: when I change the name to `JJJJ`

It will say Missing Table: `REPORT_JJJJ`

so for some reason there it is auto appending `REPORT_`

Configuration:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

Comment: Full pojo class defines problem in a better way.

Comment: just a comment: you shouldn't leave spaces after "@Table(name", it may cause unexpected problems. Better is @Table(name="REPORT_WORK")

Comment: @HoàngLong the space are auto appended by eclipse formating

Comment: @user4127: I heard a friend saying that... not sure though.

Comment: @user4127: I think you may need to use -Dhibernate.show_sql=true to check the SQL statements, maybe it gives some hint

Comment: @HoàngLong - your friend is wrong.  It makes no difference having spaces there or not.

Comment: @StephenC: are you sure? I'm pretty confident about his knowledge, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @user4127: maybe you are using some kind of Custom Naming Strategy?

Comment: @HoàngLong - Yes I'm sure.  These are Java annotations, and whitespace is not significant between lexical symbols in Java source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is your Hibernate configurations.  Specifically, if you don't have an appropriate setting for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`, Hibernate won't automatically update the database schema when you change your model.

(And if you don't want the updates to happen automatically, then you need to figure out what schema changes are needed, code them as SQL DDL, and run them manually.)

Comment: hi I am using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate

Comment: @user4127 - Well that would explain it.  "validate" won't update your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your persistence.xml (or equivalent)?

It sounds like you are implementing org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy, get rid of this configuration.

Some additional info:
[JPA (Hibernate) and custom table prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313095/jpa-hibernate-and-custom-table-prefixes)