# Is it possible to map tables with prefixes?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I am pretty new in hibernate community so I do not know which direction to choose. Basically I have an war and db for it, but I have my own project with db. the problem is that some of the tables have the same names, thus is it possible somehow to map tables so the other project will call prefixed table (not the original, e.g. PREFIX_TEST, while originally TEST). I read about Naming Strategy, but I;m not sure if I can use it, I have no persistence.xml

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the prefixing is only needed for several tables, you can either define the table mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PREFIX_TEST")
public class Test { ... }
```

or create an entity with a name matching the prefixed table:

```
@Entity
public class PrefixTest { ... }
```

If you want to modify the names of all tables, you can use a naming strategy as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617687/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-define-column-names-in-hibernate-jpa/3618315).

However you would need a `persistence.xml` for that.

EDIT: The fact that you only have access to the packaged application is not a big issue if all you want to change is the `persistence.xml`. A `[jwe]ar` file is a simple `zip` file, so you can unpack it, add or change the `persistence.xml`, repack and deploy.

Comment: I cannot change the annotation, I have it all packed in war.

Comment: If you want to use different table names, you will have to change something - either the annotations or the classes or the persistence.xml

Comment: So there is no other way how can I wrap it? :(

Comment: I'm afraid not. Changing the behaviour without changing neither the code nor the configuration is not possible.

Comment: There may be a way though, if you are willing to tinker with the contents of the .war file. Please see the edit.

Comment: sorry for stupid question, if I will be able to change the persistence.xml how should I do that, I mean do you have some example please?

Comment: No problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617687/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-define-column-names-in-hibernate-jpa/3618315