# Parametrize objectname in jpql query for postgresql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, playframework-2.2

I am using play with JPA with PostgreSQL and having a problem creating a jpql.

Below is my model code

```
public static List<Jobseekers> search(String key, String keyvalue) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Jobseekers> empList = JPA.em().createQuery("FROM Jobseekers WHERE :key LIKE :keyvalue").setParameter("key", key).setParameter("keyvalue", "%"+keyvalue+"%").getResultList();
       System.out.println("key is"+key);
        return empList;
    }
```

so my column name is dynamic in query

The sql that is created is like

```
select * from jobseekers where 'name' like '%akash%'
```

where name is the key

The above query gives an empty list because of the appostrophe(') in name column name

My problem is that how to remove appostrophe(') in column name('name') so I can get correct result?

Comment: Your problem isn't how to escape apostrophes, your problem is that a prepared statement with `:key` doesn't handle dynamic SQL the way it handles values. I don't know the answer but you should change the title and possibly the question to reflect this.

Comment: Maybe **[this is helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617687/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-define-column-names-in-hibernate-jpa)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't parametrize object names. Parameters are only for values. You need to include `key` in the query itself (which potentially opens you up for SQL injection!).

So you need to do:

```
List<Jobseekers> empList = JPA.em().createQuery("FROM Jobseekers WHERE " + 
        key + " LIKE :keyvalue")
    .setParameter("keyvalue", "%"+keyvalue+"%")
    .getResultList();
```

The other option is to use the criteria API to build the query, but that is a lot more complex; and I haven't used it a lot, so I can't provide an example.

Comment: Be careful when you concatenate something in a query, you could take a sql injection attack.

Comment: @uaiHebert Which is exactly why I mention that in my answer.